# IDA Pro 7.5 Breakpoint Python Script: 'invalid non-printable character U+FEFF'

Tags: ida, python

I'm trying to set a python condition breakpoint, but it throws me a weird error and I don't understand what happens:

[image: Edit Breakpoint fails]

Even if I just return True, it throws the same error when I compile or when press "OK" twice.

[image: Python console]

The python console works fine. IDC works fine.

IDA Pro v7.5.200728
Python 3.9.5

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

**Solve**:

**https://hex-rays.com/blog/python-3-9-support-for-ida-7-5/
Download the patch and replace the files.**

Comment: If you have solved your problem please write a full answer.

Answer (score -1):

Solve:

https://hex-rays.com/blog/python-3-9-support-for-ida-7-5/ Download the patch and replace the files.